# R: Merge Data While Retaining Values for One Dataset in Duplicates

Tags: r, merge, duplicates

I have two data sets, `data1` and `data2`:

```
data1 <- data.frame(ID = 1:6,
                    A = c("a1", "a2", NA, "a4", "a5", NA),
                    B = c("b1", "b2", "b3", NA, "b5", NA),
                    stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
data1

ID  A   B
1   a1  b1      
2   a2  b2      
3   NA  b3      
4   a4  NA      
5   a5  b5
6   NA  NA
```

and

```
data2 <- data.frame(ID = 1:6,
                    A = c(NA, "a2", "a3", NA, "a5", "a6"),
                    B = c(NA, "b2.wrong", NA, "b4", "b5", "b6"),
                    stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
data2

ID  A   B
1   NA  NA
2   a2  b2.wrong        
3   a3  NA      
4   NA  b4      
5   a5  b5
6   a6  b6
```

I would like to merge them by `ID` so that the resultant merged dataset, `data.merged`, populates fields form both datasets, but chooses values from `data1` whenever there are possible values from both datasets.

I.e., I would like the final dataset, `data.merge`, to be:

```
ID  A   B
1   a1  b1      
2   a2  b2      
3   a3  b3      
4   a4  b4      
5   a5  b5      
6   a6  b6
```

I have looked around, finding [similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55854499/how-do-i-combine-duplicate-rows-without-losing-unique-data-in-r-or-vba) but not exact answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can join the data and use `coalesce` to select the first non-NA value.

```
library(dplyr)

data1 %>%
  inner_join(data2, by = 'ID') %>%
  mutate(A = coalesce(A.x, A.y), 
         B = coalesce(B.x, B.y)) %>%
  select(names(data1))

#  ID  A  B
#1  1 a1 b1
#2  2 a2 b2
#3  3 a3 b3
#4  4 a4 b4
#5  5 a5 b5
#6  6 a6 b6
```

Or in base R comparing values with `NA` :

```
transform(merge(data1, data2, by = 'ID'), 
          A = ifelse(is.na(A.x), A.y, A.x),
          B = ifelse(is.na(B.x), B.y, B.x))[names(data1)]
```